# How to output TOC without any clutter

Tags: table-of-contents

`\tableofcontents` will output stuff around the actual TOC depending on the document class (e.g. a headline for the TOC itself, pagebreaks, whitespace, ...). How do I output only the TOC-part (the lines with titles, dots and pagenumber), starting with the first and ending with the last actual entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line, type `latexdef -s \tableofcontents`, and return

```
% article.cls, line 503:
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
```

Just redefine `\tableofcontents`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{test}
\end{document}
```